# Processing not working

Tags: processing

I'm trying to run this code in processing:
This is the simple code..

```
void setup()
{
  size(400,400);
  background(255,255,0);
}
void draw()
{
  ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,40,40);
  fill(0,255,255);
  strokeWeight(5);

}
```

But when i click run button i see no output,but get this:

```
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at processing.app.contrib.ContributionManager.download(ContributionManager.java:62)
at processing.app.contrib.ContributionListing$2.run(ContributionListing.java:362)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at processing.app.contrib.ContributionManager.download(ContributionManager.java:62)
at processing.app.contrib.ContributionListing$2.run(ContributionListing.java:362)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have downloaded java jdk for windows 7 x64,processing 2.2.1...please help me!

Comment: Are you sure that's the _only_ code in the editor? Are you maybe in JavaScript mode (check the box in the upper right)? The ContributionManager (mentioned in the stack trace) is used for installing new modes...

Comment: copy-pasted your code into the IDE downloaded from http://processing.org, and your code works just fine. As it should because there's nothing in this code that uses the internet.

Comment: Exactly, and no I'm working in java not javascript mode!

Answer (score 2):

I ran your code with processing 2.2.1 both Java and Javascript mode.. and working ._.

Since I saw that: "`java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect`"
I recommend to Check Firewall, antivirus, install Javascript mode, reboot computer, re-create the sketch, move the sketch directory...

Answer (score 0):

The code is valid.

Do you have any sketches working, or is this the first. If so, I would suggest uninstalling and reinstall. Sounds as though something is missing. Also, processing 3 is now out with debug added.